# Returning part of the array inside MongoDB Collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a users collection:

```
{
  "_id": "5fb3f05fa664961df03e2b7a",
  "username": "testy",
  "count": 3,
  "exercises": [
  {
    "description": "test1",
    "duration": "1",
    "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "description": "test2",
    "duration": "10",
    "date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "description": "test3",
    "duration": "100",
    "date": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to partially return some of the exercises that match my queries. Two of these queries are date range:

```
&from=2020-01&to=2020-02
```

I come across `$elemMatch`, but I can't get the result I want. It just returns the whole exercises array.
This is how I tried to use it:

```
const from = req.query.from
let query = {}
query._id = userId
if (from) {
  query.exercises = { $elemMatch: { date: { $gte: new Date(from) } } }
}
```

And this is how I create my exercises array:

```
$push: {
    exercises: {
      description,
      duration,
      date: new Date(date || getCurrentStringDate())
    },
```

What I want eventually is such a result:

```
{
  "_id": "5fb3f05fa664961df03e2b7a",
  "username": "testy",
  "count": 3,
  "exercises": [
  {
    "description": "test1",
    "duration": "1",
    "date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "description": "test2",
    "duration": "10",
    "date": "2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
 ]
}
```

when these queries are given in the URL:

```
&from=2020-01&to=2020-02
```

Am I using the `$elemMatch` wrong? Or it isn't the solution for this case at all?

Comment: I think you can use `query['exercises.date'] = { $gte: new Date(from) }`.

Comment: In your sample document `date` field is of type `string`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about using `$elemMatch`. It wasn't a solution for my case. Eventually I ended up using this pipeline for `Collection.aggregate` and used `$project` to create a new filtered array(via `$filter` and `$cond`):

```
let dateRange = []
  if (from) {
    dateRange.push({$gte: [ "$$item.date", from]})
  }
  if (to) {
    dateRange.push({$lte: [ "$$item.date", to]})
  }
  if (dateRange.length !== 0) {
    pipeline.push({
      $project: {
        log: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$log",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $and: dateRange }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Most probably it's not the best solution but worked for my problem.